# Nonresident alien working remotely for a US company - will I have problems with IRS?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, irs

I' not a US citizen. I work a US company remotely while living in a different country. according to the US laws, I am a nonresident alien of the US and my income source is from a non-US source. Thus, I don't owe the US any income tax. I am considering receiving my payments to my Wise USD account via internal (US) wire transfers.

Will the IRS think that I might be a US resident avoiding taxes and create problems for me? If yes, what kind of problems and how to solve them? Will Wise think that my transactions are suspicious or something like that and block me? What documents are they likely to demand from me?

Comment: They won't think you're a resident. This wouldn't be suspicious for a "normal" international bank account. I don't know whether it would have tax implications.

Answer (score 2):

As long as your employer does everything correctly (i.e.: don't issue you a W2 with a SSN or have any FICA or income tax withholding to IRS or any US local entity) - you should be fine.